# Merge [gorilla-toolkit] into [gorilla]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla) tag has 291 questions, and this description:

> Gorilla is a web toolkit for the Go programming language. It provides several modules to aid web programming: a URL router and dispatcher, a consistent session management system, and a http.response-struct mapper. It is licensed under the New BSD License.

And [gorilla-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla-toolkit) 74 questions and this description:

> Gorilla is a web toolkit for the Go programming language.

The direction of the merge isn't so important, but I think these two tags ought to be combined.

Comment: Can you or another expert review the questions with these tags and ensure that they are actually ready for a merge? In other words, can you make sure there aren't any questions about apes hidden under the [tag:gorilla] tag? Or questions about some other framework called Gorilla unrelated to Go?

Comment: @CodyGray https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118197/gorilla-vs-shark-who-would-win was the only odd one.

Comment: Strongly tempted to undelete so I can +1 for that ballin ASCII art.

Comment: Hey hey, you handled that post earlier @Cody... should have done it before.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the comments in time to do the requisite investigation. Thanks to those who did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through all the questions tagged [gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla) and found out that all of them [except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118197/gorilla-vs-shark-who-would-win) were related to the Gorilla toolkit. Additionally 50 questions had both the tags already.

I merged [gorilla-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla-toolkit) into [gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla), as [gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gorilla) was the more famous tag.